# Quagga Barcode OnDetected Keeps firing on apple mobile

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, barcode, quagga

I have a PWA app using the Quagga Barcode library. It works fine on desktop but in mobile mode on apple iphone12 once it detects a barcode the OnDetected keeps firing over and over. On the OnDetected routine i simply put a alert to display code scanned.

Comment: The code for OnDetected im using is                                         
Quagga.onDetected(function (result) {
 var code = result.codeResult.code;
 alert("Code is = " + code);
});

Comment: have you always had the `alert` in onDetected? `alert` isn't the best way to debug javascript as it blocks execution so things can behave differently with/without it

Comment: Hi i changed it to the below and got the screen quickly filling with the words found code after one scan.                                                                                                                     var code = result.codeResult.code;
var list = document.getElementById("ProdList");
              if (result.codeResult.code) {
               //alert("found code");
               list.innerText = list.innerText + "Found code";
              }